# "Unable to start debugging on the web server" MSVSMON.EXE failed to start error in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net, iis-7.5

I have a real problem getting VS2010 to debug IIS, using Windows 7 64 Bit.

I've searched on the internet for a few days now and tried every single solution I can, going through every IIS setting possible.  VS2008 works perfectly but I've installed VS2010 and when trying to debug an IIS site (by pressing F5 on a project that uses IIS) I get the error message:

> unable to start debugging on the web server.
>   Microsoft Visual Studio Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) failed to start.
>   If this problem persists, please repair your Visual installation via "add or remove programs" in the control panel."

When I try attaching the process manually, I get the same message.

I've tried repairing the software.  I tried it, it failed, so I uninstalled using the  [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4321), then reinstalled and it still has the same problem.  With the SP1 update this still happens.  I can run the website fine when running "start without debugging" and it runs fine.

I also have a laptop and have done the same, installing VS2010 and TFS (also on Windows 7 64bit), and this works perfectly for debugging.  Didn't have to mess around at all.  I can't see any difference between this and my PC with the problem.